# Uniform continuity of a function on an interval

Tags: continuity, uniform-continuity

Let $h : (0, +\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be the function defined by
$$h(x) = \cos(2x) + x\sin(1/x).$$

Prove that $h$ is uniformly continuous on $(0, +\infty)$.

My attempt: $h$ is uniformly continuous on $(0, +\infty)$ if for each $\epsilon>0$, there's a $\delta>0$ such that $|h(x)-h(y)|<\epsilon$ for all $|x-y|<\delta$, $x,y\in (0, +\infty)$.

Comment: *How* is that an attempt? All you did was to state what uniform continuity means.

Comment: First note that $\lim_{x\to0}x\sin(1/x)=0$. Therefore, $\lim_{x\to0}h(x)=1$. Next observe that $\lim_{x\to+\infty}x\sin(1/x)=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{\sin(1/x)}{1/x}=1$. Therefore, the function $h$ gets closer and closer to $\cos(3x)+1$ as $x\to+\infty$. Given $\epsilon>0$. You can pick $M$ large enough such that $|x\sin(1/x)-1|<\epsilon/4$. By Cantor's theorem $h$, extended by $h(0)=1$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,M]$. Now, on $[M,+\infty)$ you have that $|h(x)-h(y)|\leq|\cos(3x)-\cos(3y)|+|x\sin(1/x)-y\sin(1/y)|\leq|\cos(3x)-\cos(3y)|+\epsilon/2$.

Comment: By Cantor's theorem $\cos(3x)$ is uniformly continuous on any interval $[2k\pi,2(k+1)\pi]$. Since $\cos(3x)$ is periodic, it is uniformly continuous on $[M,+\infty)$. Therefore, there is $\delta>0$ such that if $|x-y|<\delta$ and $x,y\geq M$, then $|\cos(3x)-\cos(3y)|<\epsilon/2$.

Comment: Please see [**How can I format mathematics here?**](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and pages linked from there.